# Create inner_join table or create new table MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, inner-join, sql-insert

I have two tables in my ClassSelector DB:

**students**

student_id  |  student_name |  hometown

**classes**

class_id  |  classname |  description

I am trying to write a program that will take a user-entered student_id and allow them to select a class from a list of class ID's.  I want the application to write student_id, student_name, class_id, classname to a separate table.  To do this, would it be best to create a new table(student_x_class) and use an INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO ClassSelector.student_x_class ClassSelector.students.student_id,ClassSelector.students.student_name, ClassSelector.classes.class_id,ClassSelector.classes.classname VALUES(W, X, Y, Z);
```

or create a new column in the classes table (student_x_class) and use this as a foreign key to the student_id column and use inner join.

Sorry if this is confusing, I'm new to MySQL.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
ResultSet rs3 = myStmt3.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ClassSelector.classes WHERE class_id = " + selectedClass);
    while(rs3.next()){
                            String innerJoin = (userEnterId + " has been added to " + rs3.getString("classname") + " " + rs3.getString("class_id"));
                            System.out.println(innerJoin);
                            String student_classJoin = "INSERT INTO students_x_classes" + "(student_name, class_id, classname)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                            PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(student_classJoin);
                            pStmt.setString(1, userEnterId);
                            pStmt.setString(2, rs2.getString("class_id"));
                            pStmt.setString(3, rs2.getString("classname"));
                            pStmt.executeUpdate();
                            input.close();
                        }
```

Comment: sorry, radoh, I changed where it said INSERT INTO students to students_x_classes.  I want to take the columns from the students table and classes table and insert them into the students_x_classes table; I think I'm doing this incorrectly though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since student-classes is an `M:N` relationship (meaning 1 student can attend many classes and 1 class can have many students) I would suggest you create table `student_x_class` with columns `(class_id, student_id)`.

Then you can select all classes for a specific student with a simple join select

```
SELECT *
FROM students s
  INNER JOIN student_x_class sc ON sc.student_id = s.student_id
  INNER JOIN classes c ON c.class_id = sc.class_id
WHERE s.student_id = ?
```

When you want to `INSERT` rows into the `student_x_class` table, you don't need to join anything. Simply insert the class_id and student_id pair (no need for classname in that table), e.g.

```
String student_classJoin = "INSERT INTO student_x_class" + "(student_id, class_id)" + "VALUES (?, ?)";
```

And don't forget to adjust the binds, i.e. remove line `pStmt.setString(3, rs2.getString("classname"));`

Btw this is really basic stuff, try reading some SQL book/tutorial to get the whole concept.

Comment: so would the "?" be the user-entered student ID?

Comment: Ok, thanks!
Now if I wanted to have this MySQL statement to be in a Java app and write this inner_join to the database through java how could I do that?

Comment: I added what I have so far from my java code to the OP.

Comment: @Rassisland I'm slightly confused now - are you asking how to `INSERT` values into the `student_x_class` or how to do the `SELECT`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I'm confused, too.  I'm trying to use Java to write the student_name, id, classname, id to the student_x_class table.

Comment: thanks for the help, I know this is pretty basic, I've just gotten myself all mixed up.  I appreciate your patience.  So do I still use the prepared statements for the other two columns?

Comment: @Rassisland yes, and as I've mentioned in my answer - don't forget to adjust the binds

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the nature of the student-class relation. If a given class is only related to one student (let's imagine is its delegate or something like that) then a foreign key in classes table would be enough. If a class can be related to more than one student then you should think in creating a new table to model that relation. If you use this second approach, a good recommendation would be to include in the new table only the two ids.